# how do you skip the last line w/ awk?

Tags: unix, awk

I am processing a file with awk and need to skip some lines. The internet dosen't have a good answer.

So far the only info I have is that you can skip a range by doing:

```
awk 'NR==6,NR==13 {print}' input.file
```

OR

```
awk 'NR <= 5 { next } NR > 13 {exit} { print}' input.file
```

You can skip the first line by inputting:

```
awk 'NR < 1 { exit } { print}' db_berths.txt
```

How do you skip the last line?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One way using `awk`:

```
awk 'NR > 1 { print prev } { prev = $0 }' file.txt
```

Or better with `sed`:

```
sed '$d' file.txt
```

Comment: The exact format of `head`'s options depends on your operating system.  rwos' suggestion works in Linux, but not in FreeBSD, OpenBSD, OS/X.  Probably also doesn't work in Solaris, HP/UX, etc.

Comment: [For those who didn't follow the awk version](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15856794/645270)

Answer (score -4):

You can try:

```
awk 'END{print NR}' file
```

Comment: -1 this will print how many lines in the input file. completely different from OP's requirement