# What is the easiest way to remove 1st and last line from file with awk?

Tags: awk

I am learning awk/gawk.  So recently I just try to solve any problem with it to gain more practice opportunities.

My coworker asked a question yesterday,

> "how to remove first and last line from file"

. I know that `sed '1d;$d' file` would work.  also `head/tail` works too even if the poor performance. I told him the sed one, he was happy.

Later, I was trying to wrote an awk one-liner: so far what I got is:

```
awk 'NR>1{a[++k]=$0}END{for(i=1;i<k;i++)print a[i]}'
```

This will store whole file in array just to skip the last line. I feel that there should be an easier(or better) way to do that..

(if there is no easier or faster or better way, I would remove the question)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
awk 'NR>2 {print last} {last=$0}'
```

`awk` executes the action `print last` only when NR > 2 (that is, on all lines but the first 2).  On all lines, it sets the variable `last` to the current line.  So when `awk` reads the third line, it prints line 2 (which was stored in `last`).  When it reads the last line (line n) it prints the content of line n-1.  The net effect is that lines 2 through n-1 are printed.

Comment: YES!!! I though of this way too, but gave `NR>1`..then gave up...urrrr. didn't think about NR>2 at all, how stupid!.. great! thank you! up!

Comment: Use `FNR` when reading multiple files. See `Two-file processing` in http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/

Comment: `gawk -i inplace 'NR>2 {print last} {last=$0}' file` if someone wants in-place edits. Requires GNU awk 4.1.0+.

Comment: @Xeverous `-i` is a minor abomination.  As long as you remember that the file is not edited "in place" at all but is replaced by a new file, it can be a useful feature.  But it remains an abomination.

Comment: Note that if it *did* actually edit the file in place, its status would be escalated to major abomination.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I get it (same as `-r` for `grep` - both are against unix philosophy of 1 job per program) but why would proper in-place be a major abomination? Some tools (e.g. `rsync`) actually work in-place for efficiency.

Comment: @Xeverous I dislike `-i` because of the inherent risk of data corruption.  `rsync` does not work in place; it transfers data to another box.

Answer (score 24):

Let me suggest another solution.
In case if you need custom N for top and bottom lines you can use **tail** and **head** commands:

```
awk '{print $1}'  | head -n -1 | tail -n+2
```

**head -n -1** - removes last line

**tail -n+2**  - starts output from second line (removes 1 line)

Following command will remove 3 lines from top and bottom:

```
awk '{print $1}'  | head -n -3 | tail -n +4
```

Actually we don't even need awk here:

```
more | head -n -1 | tail -n +2
```

or

```
cat | head -n -1 | tail -n +2
```

Thanks to [Igor Fobia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/512497/igor-fobia) for comment!

Comment: I like this solution, but now awk is superfluous. You just need to do `more filename | head -n -1 | tail -n +2`

Comment: negative number for `head -n` is not POSIX compliant. So this might not work depending on the platform. https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/utilities/head.html

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way, but it required gawk function length:

```
awk '{firstline=2; cuttail=1; l[NR]=$0} END {for (i=firstline; i<=length(l)-cuttail; i++) print l[i]}'
```