# Remove last line from all files of a specific extension

Tags: unix, awk, sed, find, file-processing

I have several files with same extension *.txt* in a directory. I want to remove the last line from all *.txt* files.

What I did is

`find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sed '$d' {} \;`

This prints the desired output from **sed** to the terminal for every *.txt* file.

What I want is to modify the respective files.

Comment: No, you really don't want to do that.  You *might* be able to use `sed -i` (if your sed supports this atrocity), but you *really* don't want to.

Comment: Create a new directory.  Filter the files into new files in the new directory with the changes.  Attempting to maniuplate large number of files with `sed -i` will work most of the time.  But it will fail and cause data loss at the worst possible moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:--

```
sed  -i '$d' *.txt
```

"$" is used as a line number and means the last line in the file.

"d" is usd to delete the respective line(last line in this case).

"*.txt" is used to select all files whose extension is .txt in the present directory.

Comment: Please describe in your answer, what was the problem, and how will this snippet solve it, to help others understand this answer

Comment: @FZs If  I am correct user want to delete last line from all file whose extension is .txt in particular directory and this command sufficient  to do that.

Comment: I've meant to explain it in your answer... You can edit it anytime! And I don't know whether you're right, I've seen this post in a review queue

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 1):

You should use -i with sed statement

To modify and do some changes in file we need to specify `-i` in sed command

your command should be like

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sed -i '$d' {} \;
```

**But please note that it will update all the files with .txt and you wont be able to revert back so please take backup of important files**

Answer (score 0):

Considering the risk of loosing data while modifying large number of files using **sed**, this is what I used after creating a new sub-directory:

`awk 'NR>1 {print last > "./modified/"FILENAME} {last=$0}' *.txt`

This filters all the files with extension *.txt* into new files with changes to the sub-directory named *modified*.

Ref: [what is the easiest way to remove 1st and last line from file with awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15856733/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-remove-1st-and-last-line-from-file-with-awk)