# Avoid to print twice the last line in awk

Tags: json, bash, awk

I'm trying to put a JSON format to a file with one column, to do this I thought that awk can be a great tool.My input is (for example):

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

And my output that I want is:

```
{nodes:[{id='a'},
{id='b'},
{id='c'},
{id='d'},
{id='e'}]}
```

I tried with two different codes. The first one is:

```
BEGIN{
FS = "\t"
printf "{nodes:["
}
{printf "{'id':'%s'},\n",$1}
END{printf "{'id':'%s'}]}\n",$1}
```

But I print twice the last line:

```
{nodes:[{id='a'},
{id='b'},
{id='c'},
{id='d'},
{id='e'},
{id='e'}]}
```

The other option that I tried is with getline:

```
BEGIN{
FS = "\t"
printf "{nodes:["
}
{printf getline==0 ? "{'id':'%s'}]}" : "{'id':'%s'},\n",$1}
```

But for some reason, getline is always 1 instead to be 0 in the last line, so:

```
{nodes:[{id='a'},
{id='b'},
{id='c'},
{id='d'},
{id='e'},
```

Any suggestion to solve my problem?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11866860/how-do-you-skip-the-last-line-w-awk

Comment: You dont use a valide json format. Every name and value needs to be surrounded by quotes `"`, except numbers and boolean values. You should use the tool `jq` to verify your json-data. Do it has to be `awk`, or can you create a simple `echo` with all the stuff in it ?

Comment: Both have reason, now my code works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In awk. Buffer the output to variable `b` and process it before outputing:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{b="{nodes:["}{b=b "{id=\x27" $0 "\x27},\n"}END{sub(/,\n$/,"]}",b);print b}' file
{nodes:[{id='a'},
{id='b'},
{id='c'},
{id='d'},
{id='e'}]}
```

Explained:

```
BEGIN { b="{nodes:[" }                  # front matter
      { b=b "{id=\x27" $0 "\x27},\n" }  # middle 
END   { sub(/,\n$/,"]}",b); print b }   # end matter and replace ,\n in the end
                                        # with something more appropriate
```

Comment: I don't understand why you put \x27

Comment: Try to replace them with `'`. https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Quoting.html

Answer (score 0):

Solution (thanks to @Ruud and @suleiman)

```
BEGIN{
FS = "\t"
printf "{'nodes':["
}
NR > 1{printf "{'id':'%s'},\n",prev}
{prev = $1}
END{printf "{'id':'%s'}]}",prev}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$awk -v count=$(wc -l < f) 'BEGIN{kk=getline;printf "{nodes:[={'id':'%s'},\n",$kk}
> {
> if(NR < count)
> {
> {printf "{'id':'%s'},\n",$1}
> }}
> END{printf "{'id':'%s'}]}\n",$1}' f
{nodes:[={id:a},
{id:b},
{id:c},
{id:d},
{id:e}]}
```