# Find the git commit where directory was first created

Tags: git

The solution that [works for file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533199/find-commit-where-file-was-added) does not work for directory. How do I know the first git commit that created a directory for the first time?

EDIT: As one of the comment points out that a directory appears in git only when a file under that directory is added to version control. In the context of this question, I don't know which file under that directory was added first.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe directories aren't logged in the same way that files are, e.g. because you need to have a file in a new directory to add it. So I would think that you would need to find out when the first file in the directory was commited.

Comment: I clarified your doubt.

Answer (score 10):

Best way I know to check a path in a lot of commits quickly is with `git cat-file --batch-check`.  List your commits in reverse i.e. oldest first with the path you're interested in and feed that to the batch checker, it will complain if the path is missing but it does so to stdout, so you can print the first line with an absence of complaints:

```
git log --reverse --pretty=$'%H:path/to/folder\t%H' \
| git cat-file --batch-check='%(rest)' \
| awk 'NF==1 { print;exit; }'
```

Comment: So convenient. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

One possible approach would be, for all files of a folder, to check [when that file was added](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13598028/6309).

```
git log --diff-filter=A -- foo.js
```

But simply using the [log for that folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11950203/6309) can also help:

```
git log -- path/to/folder
```

---

> Neither of these worked for me; my directory has no `git log` output whatsoever.

True: Git does not directly track directories. Git tracks *files*, and directories exist in Git only as part of the pathnames of tracked files. So a directory without any files currently tracked by Git will not appear in the `git log` output.
That can happen in several situations, such as:

- **The directory is empty**: Git does not track empty directories. If all files were removed from a directory, or if it was never populated with a tracked file, Git has no record of it.
- **The directory only contains untracked files or ignored files**: If a `.gitignore` file specifies patterns that match all files within the directory, Git will ignore those files and, consequently, the directory itself.
  Use `git check-ignore -v -- adirectory/aFileInside` to confirm this.
- **The files in the directory were moved or deleted in all current branches**: If the files that once existed in the directory have been moved to a different directory or deleted from all current branches, the original directory path would not show up in the `git log`.

You should look instead into the history of the entire repository and specifically target the directory in question.
That involves investigating all commits for any activity related to the directory, including additions, deletions, and modifications of files within that directory at any point in the repository's history.

First, list all objects (including deleted or moved files) affecting the directory:

```bash
git rev-list --all --objects -- path/to/folder | \
awk '{print $1}' | \
xargs -L1 git log --format="%ai %H" --reverse -- | \
head -1
```

That will generate a list of all objects in the repository's history that affect the specified directory (`git rev-list --all --objects -- path/to/folder`). `awk` will extract commit hashes from the output.
For each commit hash, `git log` is used to print the commit date and hash, sorted from oldest to newest, making sure that the first commit affecting any file within the directory is found. `head -1` picks the earliest commit, which gives the first instance of a file being added to the directory.

If the directory still seems to have no history, make sure it is not due to the presence of only untracked or ignored files. Use `git status --ignored` to see if the directory contains ignored files.

Comment: Found this helpful, would be nice to be able to reference dir creation specifically, but good enough - bit of an edge case where someone adds just an empty foldere

Comment: Neither of these worked for me; my directory has no `git log` output whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `git bisect` to find when something changed in a certain way. It operates off the assumption that the repository was right in the past, but something happened recently to make it not-right.

For this example, "good" is the directory **not** existing, and "bad" is the directory existing.

First you find a commit where it's "bad":

```
$ ls -d MyDirectory
MyDirectory/
$ git bisect start
$ git bisect bad
```

Then you find a commit where it's "good"

```
$ git checkout HEAD~1000
$ ls -d MyDirectory
ls: cannot access 'MyDirectory': No such file or directory
$ git bisect good
```

Then you either repeatedly do manual `bisect good/bad`:

```
$ if [ -d MyDirectory ]; then git bisect bad; else git bisect good; fi
```

Or you use `bisect run`:

```
$ git bisect run [ ! -d MyDirectory ]
```

At the end it'll tell you the first "bad" commit.

Answer (score 2):

Building on [@VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48760081/642311)'s answer, use `--reverse` with some [**awk**ward post-processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11866860/how-do-you-skip-the-last-line-w-awk) (sadly, `--reverse` is applied to the log *after* `-n 1`), we get:

```sh
git log -- path/to/folder | awk 'NR>1 {print last} {last=$0}; /^commit/ && ++c==2{exit}'
```

Comment: i.e. `git log --reverse -- path/to/folder | awk 'NR>1 {print last} {last=$0}; /^commit/ && ++c==2{exit}'`